# How do I remove previous event details from new event?

Tags: civievent

sorry if this is terribly obvious, but I'm new to Events. I'm trying to set up a new event, and at the bottom of the registration page details from a previous event keep coming up - as in the screenshot below. I've tried to update the address settings several times, but it won't go away. How do I get rid of this?

[image: At the bottom of the registration page there is box with the title of a previous event, and the address details in there.]

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has created a custom field set for events. I gather from you desciption of "previous event" the event that related to is in the past.

If you go to **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Custom Fields** you should see a field set named **Kodaly workshop**.  Click on **more** on the far right and **disable** the field set.